# Matriz Binaria em C

Tags: c, matriz, binary

Preciso inicializar uma matriz que contenha os valores em binario de 0 ao valor entrada, que neste caso é 15. A conversão de base e o armazentamento destes valores funciona bem até o numero 8. Porém, a partir da 9 linha, onde o ultimo digito deveria ser 1, apenas zero é impresso e isso se mantém até o final de execução. Aqui está o código que estou usando:

```
    int conversor(entrada)
{
    aux1=entrada;
    do
    {
        /*
        Na função usei o modelo da divisão continua para converter um número, que se dá da seguinte maneira:
        Usando um inteiro na base decimal, é divido constantemente até que o divisor de zero
        O resto de cada uma dessas divisões é apenas 0 ou 1, e ordendando da direita para a esquerda,
         o resultado é em binario
        */
        for (i=entrada; i>=0; i--)
        {
            do
            {
                if (aux==0)
                {
                    saida[i][aux]=entrada%2;
                    divisor=entrada/2; //Primeira iteração, usa o valor de entrada ainda
                }
                else
                {
                    saida[i][aux]=divisor%2;
                    divisor=divisor/2; //Termina de dividir o numero
                }
                aux++; //Proxima coluna
            }
            while (divisor>0); //Faz a conta enquanto o divisor for maior que zero
        }
        entrada--; //Passa para proxima linha
        aux=0; //Zera auxiliar
    }
    while (entrada>0);

    for (j=0; j<=aux1; j++)
    {
        for (i=3; i>=0; i--)
        {
            printf ("%d ",saida[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

E aqui está o resultado:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
```

Já tentei testar apenas a inicialização de array para conter o valor binário de 9, 1001, separadamente mas quando executo nesta função este erro acontece. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O que é  `entrada`? `typedef`, `#define`, você se esqueceu de escrever o tipo da variável? E por que não há a declaração de nenhuma variável? Sao todas globais?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É pertinente evitar estas transformações fazendo módulo/divisão e recorrer aos operadores de deslocamento. Facilmente, você consegue extrair os bits para resolver seu problema. Considerando um inteiro cujo valor em binário cabe em uma representação de 4 digitos:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_VALUE = 15;

int main (void) {

  int MBIN[15][4] = {{0}};

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
     MBIN[i][0] = (i >> 3) & 0x1;
     MBIN[i][1] = (i >> 2) & 0x1;
     MBIN[i][2] = (i >> 1) & 0x1;
     MBIN[i][3] = i & 0x1
   }

   // Mostrando os valores da matriz
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("%d", MBIN[i][j]);
     }
    puts("");
   }
}
```